# How to get data from database in javascript based on the value passed to the function

Tags: javascript, database

In my web application, I want to retrieve data from database based on the value that is passed to the function. I wrote the query as follows.

```
<script> 
 //Functions to open database and to create, insert data into tables

 getSelectedRow = function(val)
    {
        db.transaction(function(transaction) {
              transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Employ where number = parseInt(val);',[], selectedRowValues, errorHandler);

        });
    };
    selectedRowValues = function(transaction,results)
    {
         for(var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++)
         {
             var row = results.rows.item(i);
             alert(row['number']);
             alert(row['name']);                 
         }
    };
</script>
```

In body tag,

```
<body>
   ---
     <a href = "#" onClick = "javascript:getSelectedRow('1')>getValues</a>
```

I got the problem while retrieving data from database, i.e., at SELECT query. It doesn't accept the value parseInt(val), if I give the condition as 'name = 1' it simply accepts the condition and give the result, but it doesn't accept 'name = parseInt(val)' and throws error as 'no such column: val code: 1' 
Please tell me how to pass value in 'val'..
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: [try this answer] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610333/how-to-query-database-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'SELECT * FROM Employ where number = ' + parseInt(val, 10) + ';'
```

For example, if `val` is `"10"` then this will end up building the string:

```
"SELECT * FROM Employ where number = 10;"
```

Comment: Thank you so much Esailija, its working, but I write it as 'SELECT * FROM Employ where number = ' + parseInt(val) + ';' and i'm not passing  10

Comment: @user25 the `10` as second argument specifies the base for `parseInt`. For example, `parseInt("09", 8) === 0`, but `parseInt("09", 10) === 9`

Answer (score 2):

The error is coming as your query is getting formed as

```
SELECT * FROM Employ where number = parseInt(val);
```

I dont know which DB you are using but no DB will understand `parseInt`.

What you can do is use a variable say temp and store the value of `parseInt(val)` in temp variable and make the query as

```
SELECT * FROM Employ where number = temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<script> 
 //Functions to open database and to create, insert data into tables

 getSelectedRow = function(val)
    {
        db.transaction(function(transaction) {
              transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Employ where number = ?;',[parseInt(val)], selectedRowValues, errorHandler);

        });
    };
    selectedRowValues = function(transaction,results)
    {
         for(var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++)
         {
             var row = results.rows.item(i);
             alert(row['number']);
             alert(row['name']);                 
         }
    };
</script>
```

You don't have access to javascript variable names in SQL, you must pass the values to the Database.