# PHP: How do I can get data from SQL in my Javascript based on a value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, yii2

I've an application, developed using **Yii2** framework. In my application, I've a view.php that has an **element** and a **button**. The **element** `<div id="userId">` contain the `id` of login user, and I want to use the **button** to get *data* from column that called `header_name` from `header_table` in my **SQL** based on the `id` that has got from the **element**.

This is the code

#### View.php

```
<?php
   //some code
?>
<div id="userId" style="display: none"> <?php echo $userId; ?> </div> 
<p>
<button type="button" onclick="getHeader()"class="headerBtn">Use Saved Header</button>
<p>
```

and

#### upload_header.js

```
function getHeader(){
   var id = document.getElementById('userId').textContent;
}
```

I've successfully get the `$userid` from view.php in my upload_header.js. But I dont't know how to get the data from sql.

#### How do I can get data from SQL through javascript?

Thanks, any help will be appreciated :)

#### Note:

I've read [How to get data from database in javascript based on the value passed to the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027982/how-to-get-data-from-database-in-javascript-based-on-the-value-passed-to-the-fun) and try the suggestion, but it didn't solve my case. Thanks

Comment: You don't need a `<div>` for that, you can for instance add the id as `data-id` attribute to the button. Anyway, you need AJAX. It allows you to request a resource from the server, in the background, without leaving the page. You'll request a php script, which in turn sends back the result of the db query.

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX in getHeader function.

i.e.

```
$.ajax({url: "server_page.php?userId="+id, success: function(result){
        //Your Result here
    }});
```

You can return data in JSON format from server page and parse in ajax success area.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax for this

**upload_header.js**

```
function getHeader(){
   var id = document.getElementById('userId').textContent;
   $.ajax({
       type:"POST", // or GET
       url:"<?= Url::to(['controller-name/function-name']) ?>",
       data:{id:id},
       success:function(response){
            console.log(response); //your data from sql
      }
   });
}
```

**on_your_contoller.php**

```
public function function-name(){
     $id = $POST['id'];
     return User::findOne($id);
}
```