# Return data when click on drop-down button

Tags: php, html, css

Here I have a drop-down Menu like this:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
  <button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Choose A Day
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
    <a class="dropdown-item" value="Monday" >Monday</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" value="Tuesday" >Tuesday</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" value="Wednesday" >Wednesday</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" value="Thursday">Thursday</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" value="Friday">Friday</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" value="Saturday">Saturday</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I also have a empty table:

```
<table border="2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Lesson_id</td>
      <td>Teacher</td>
      <td>Lesson</td>
      <td>Day</td>
      <td>Time</td>
      <td>Classroom</td>
      <td>Year</td>
      <td>Curriculum</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

And I have a php function:

```
<?php
function get_data_from_day($day)
{
include('dbh.inc.php');
global $conn;
$query = "SELECT * FROM  ";
$result = $conn->query($query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Lesson_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Teacher'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Lesson'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Day'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Time'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Classroom'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Year'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Curriculum'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
}
```

Finally I have a database name school.Inside that is 6 table from monday to friday.I want to retrieve data from the database when click the drop-down menu.For example, if I click the monday button will return all data from table monday and so on. Is there any solution for this

Comment: the solution is to write code that do that ... here we help you fixing issue and debugging not doing the work for you. So try to do it and if you face an issue you can get back here and it will be a pleasure to help you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to do it with php, because php runs before the page is loaded in the server. Instead I would use javascript or jquery; I found here:

[How to get data from database in javascript based on the value passed to the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027982/how-to-get-data-from-database-in-javascript-based-on-the-value-passed-to-the-fun)

How to get data from database in javascript.

I think you could use something similar to this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase.html

First open the database:

```
try {
    if (!window.openDatabase) {
        alert('not supported');
    } else {
        var shortName = 'mydatabase';
        var version = '1.0';
        var displayName = 'My Important Database';
        var maxSize = 65536; // in bytes
        var db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);

        // You should have a database instance in db.
    }
} catch(e) {
    // Error handling code goes here.
    if (e == 2) {
        // Version number mismatch.
        alert("Invalid database version.");
    } else {
        alert("Unknown error "+e+".");
    }
    return;
}
```

Then you can create a function where you have your SQL query:

```
function errorHandler(transaction, error)
{
    // error.message is a human-readable string.
    // error.code is a numeric error code
    alert('Oops.  Error was '+error.message+' (Code '+error.code+')');

    // Handle errors here
    var we_think_this_error_is_fatal = true;
    if (we_think_this_error_is_fatal) return true;
    return false;
}

function dataHandler(transaction, results)
{
    // Handle the results
    var string = "Green shirt list contains the following people:\n\n";
    for (var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++) {
        // Each row is a standard JavaScript array indexed by
        // column names.
        var row = results.rows.item(i);
        string = string + row['name'] + " (ID "+row['id']+")\n";
    }
    alert(string);
}
function getSQLData(day){
db.transaction(
    function (transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql("SELECT * from " + day + ";",
            [], // array of values for the ? placeholders
            dataHandler, errorHandler);
    }
);
}
```

Then you can call the function like this:

```
 <a class="dropdown-item" value="Monday" onClick="javascript:getSQLData('Monday');" >Monday</a>
```

Hope this can give you an idea about how you could do it.