# How to set a default value for a select element?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, sql

I have a select element in HTML. I save just selected value in DB. When I want to edit this element in users side , I need to show value that selected before. I see  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-to-set-default-value-for-html-select-element/14343211#14343211). but in this link user himself determines default value,while I want to have an editable select element.
I should first retrieve selected value from DB , then set it as default value to my select element. how can I do it in JavaScript?

Comment: JavaScript alone can't do this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610333/how-to-query-database-using-javascript

Comment: Why do you want to set it via JavaScript? You can set `selected` attribute in backend to your desired `option` element. See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) here

Comment: @Mohsen: in my project , Admin can edit any select element. I want to show to admin the value that selected before then edit it. I think it cant do by backend.

Comment: @musical_coder: how can I do it in Asp.net?

Comment: That's a broad topic, but this will get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/k4cbh4dh.aspx

Comment: what's wrong with setting the SelectedIndex property of the dropdownlist?!