# Query database directly from javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, database

Can I fetch data directly from a database using java-script.

Something like

```
var results = conn.query("select * from table");
```

then use in my html

```
document.innerHtml(results[0]['name']);
```

Comment: I think you'll get a security issue if you want to do this on the client side.

Comment: Can you describe the context? It's a local database? Your database is hosted by a server?

Comment: @Tjasun Ya, i have thought about that. Firstly, i am trying to find a way that can we do this? Then if its possible, i will find a way for security also.

Comment: @R3tep How does that matter? if its local or on a server

Comment: You should look into AJAX http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: @SeijiSchoch I have Looked into AJAX, but i found no way to skip server side coding

Comment: You can setup a node.js server (it's pretty simple) and there you can use js (server side) for your query. Then use ajax for getting the data from the backend to your client or just use a node project.

Comment: @SahilJain With local you have solutions. With server you can use AJAX

Comment: @Tjasun My point is that, i am trying to find a way to skip server side

Comment: ' skip server side coding' Not possible...

Comment: @R3tep Ya, i also think that its not possible till now. Can't find any way to do this

Comment: The you have to use ActiveXObject. A sample you can see in answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript. But most clients not allows ActiveX.

Comment: ActiveXObject working only for IE

Answer (score 0):

YES. You can do it - you can query some database engines directly from Javascript. But you almost never do it, because in AJAX model you have thin clients with no fast access to database engine.

See: [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5610430/540341),